# Alternative for the ActiveX object

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, openxml, openxml-sdk

I need open a ms word document (Doc/Docx) then need to edit and save it in client side itsetf.forthat i'm using ActiveXObject and javascript.it is working fine with IE but it's not working in other browsers(Chrome,Firefox).

```
                var w = new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');
                w.Visible = true; 
                obj = w.Documents.Open("D:\\test.docx");
                docText = obj.Content;
                w.Selection.TypeText("Hello world!");
                w.Documents.Save();
```

what is the Alternative for the ActiveX object for the other browsers excluding IE (OR) **How can i edit a word document (Doc/Docx) by using client side scripting for Chrome , firefox**?

Answer (score 0):

Short version, you can't.

ActiveX is a propriety IE/Microsoft technology, and can only be relied on within IE.

Are there other avenues you can go down?

- Create a browser plugin for each browser..
- Office 365?